# How do I filter a model object and update a view in django?

Tags: python, django, filtering

I have a a template with an html table in django.  At the top of the view is a small form for input.  Something like:

```
 {% csrf_token %}
<form method="post" name="some_name" action="/myApp/">
  search button here
  ...
</form>
<table>
 loop through data and make table here
</table>
```

I when I access the webpage, I initialize data into the table.  I have a backend sqlite database with > 25 million rows.  I'd like to use the user input from the form to filter the data.  I've already tried to get the data from the form, but when I try to apply objects.all.filter(some_condition), I don't see the table update.  What am I doing wrong?  Or has anyone else come up with a solution to this type of problem?  I know this should be simple, but I've had a time figuring it out.  Thanks!

UPDATE:

views.py

```
def showTable(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':

       #I have a table of aircraft entries.The EntriesTable has a ForeignKey
       #referencing an AircraftTable that has the numbers of aircraft
       #some_name will reference the number of the aircraft

        aircraft = request.POST.get('some_name', None)
        query_results = EntriesTable.objects.all().filter(aircraft__exact = filterable)
        template=loader.get_template('myApp/showTable.html')
        context=RequestContext(request, {'query_results': query_results,})
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
   else:
       query_results = EntriesTable.objects.all().filter(start_time__range(start, stop)) #Assume that I have correctly filtered on start/stop times.  I am able to render that so far without issue.
       context= RequestContext(request, {'query_results': query_results,})
       return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: what does your view function look like?

Comment: Updated with views.py

Answer (score 0):

```
 query_results = EntriesTable.objects.filter(aircraft__exact = filterable)
```

You have an error in your view, the syntax should me:

NameOfModelClass.objects.filter(conditions)

I believe that will fix the problem